# Which one is the message and which one the entity in HTTP terminology?

Tags: http

I am trying to make better sense of HTTP internals, and often "entities" and "messages" are mentioned in the specification, strangely enough without proper explanation though, believe it or not. From what I gathered, one identifies the content itself, even when split across a request / response chain and/or transfer encoding fragmentation rules, while the other identifies content of a single HTTP request - i.e. what follows the headers and ends with a CRLF. My problem is I cannot figure out which one is which exactly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A [*HTTP-message*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.1) is either a *request* or a *response*:

> ```
>   HTTP-message   = Request | Response     ; HTTP/1.1 messages
> ```

A *HTTP-message* has zero or more *message-header*⁠s and may have a *message-body*:

> ```
>    generic-message = start-line
>                      *(message-header CRLF)
>                      CRLF
>                      [ message-body ]
> ```

So not every *HTTP-message* has a *message-body*. But if it has a *message-body*, then that’s also the *entity-body*:

> ```
>   message-body = entity-body
>                | <entity-body encoded as per Transfer-Encoding>
> ```

So in short: A message is the whole HTTP request or response. And the entity is the message’s body (if there is any) and its corresponding [entity header fields](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.1).

Comment: Ok, but what is an entity-body in the above? Let us consider a POST request with content type specified as "multipart/form-data" that carries file data, and a couple of variable-value pairs. In the request, a message is the entire request, header and all, right? The body of the message is the binary blob that follows the headers, right? The thing is, I think entity body is something else... Anyways, as you can see, I am almost as confused as I was...

Comment: @amn: The entity is in the message. The entity is the sum of *entity-header* ⁠s and the *entity-body* (the *message-body*). Some of the *message-header* ⁠s describe the message and some describe the entity. *Date*, for example, is a *message-header* (it describes the message) and *Content-Type* is a *entity-header* (it describes the entity).

Comment: Yes, that explains it all, thanks! I figured that a message encodes and transfers an entity, while entity has a type - and so both are defined by different headers.